A conductor is floating in the air and it suddenly makes contact with the positive terminal of a battery. Does current flow through the conductor?
I know that one needs a potential difference and a continuous closed path for the current to flow. My question is, when in the vicinity of this positive terminal, is the conductor's potential the same as the positive terminal even without any physical connection between the 2? Do all the points in a given electric field have the same potential? If I know the potential at a point in space, how can I calculate the potential at a distance $r$ from it if I don't know anything about the charge causing the electric field?
Imagine opening up a defective parachute and then making contact with a live wire with both hands. Do I get zapped ? :)

If current needs a continuous path, explain how capacitors work. The stray conductor has some capacitance to ground, and will try to charge.

"I know that one needs a potential difference and a continuous closed path for the current to flow." Current flows to a capacitor and it is not a "closed" path.

This might help - Watch electricity hit a fork in the road at half a billion frames per second

When not in contact with the positive terminal of the battery, the conductor have a different potential than that of the terminal.
Since, potential at a point $P$ is defined as the work done in taking a unit charge from infinity (or any useful reference point) to that point $P$.
So, in going from the positive terminal to the conductor there is some electric field in between, against which we must do work (hence, changing the potential) to take a charge to the conductor.
Now, if one knows potential at some point in space, then to know the potential at $r$ distance away from that, it is a must to know the configuration of that direction in which we move $r$ distance with respect to the position of charge distribution.
For example, if we are at some point in the vicinity of a positive charge and the potential there is $V$. Then, if we move towards the charge and away from the charge, the potential increases and decreases respectively.
Edit
Now, the parachute question. You aren't zapped. That's because when you touch the live wires you have got one end of the potential (higher) and your body is a conductor. Now, since the other potential is not present (you feet are hanging in air), so the circuit is not complete and hence the current doesn't flow.

so whatdo you consider the answer here?

@trula Read the last second paragraph

I can't se an answer, is he zapped or not?

@trula Ah that, no he isn't. But that paragraph which I mentioned answers the conceptual question asked above that question which you are pointing to.

@RudrashisPoddar Sorry for that I didn't mentioned that zapped or not in my previous answer. You can check the edit now to get the answer.
